# Expressjs + handlebars formatting date

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, mustache, momentjs

i've got this object

```
{ title: 'A TITLE',
  description: 'Lorem Ipsum...',
  _id: 50806930bbf612a858000013,
  __v: 0,
  screenings: 
   [ { venue: 'Venue1', dates: [Object] },
     { venue: 'Venue2', dates: [Object] } ] }
```

coming out of my mongoDB.

`dates` is a list of dates (dah!).

My issue is now I want to have them formatted with momentjs **server-side**.

It would look like I should be using mustache lambdas, but it appears impossible using my stack (**expressjs**, **consolidate**, **handlebars**...)

Anybody solved this?

Here's what I'm trying now

```
Theatre.find({"screenings.dates":{$gte:lastSunday, $lte:nextSunday}}, function(err, entities){
    res.render('index', {
        entities: entities,
        giveitatry: function(a) {
            return moment(a).format("MMM Do YY")
        }
    });
});
```

and on my template I have:

```
{{#entities}}
<div class="span3">{{#giveitatry}} {{dates.0.}} {{/giveitatry}}</div>
{{/entities}}
```

Here's part of the expressjs conf

```
var moment = require('moment');

var express = require('express')
  , cons = require('consolidate')
  , name = 'mustache';

app.configure(function(){
 app.set('view engine', 'hjs');
 app.engine('.hjs', cons.mustache);
 ...
```

yes, extension's still hjs 'cause i started using hogan but i wasn't able to do it with hogan so i moved to consolidate+mustache.

i'm using node v0.8.8 and expressjs 3.0.0rc4

Comment: Do you want to format then in server- or in client-side? Also can you add some example code, maybe I can help then?

Comment: Also why do you have both mustache and handlebars or are you just considering which one to use?

Comment: @jsalonen i wanted a mustache-like template and the closest built-in thing looked like hogan but was not working so we figured we could use consolidate with handlebars but it's not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use mustache.js lambdas, you need to return a function instead. The parameters for this function are `text`, which contains textual representation of the template content and `render` that can be explicitly invoked to render the template.

The best solution I have found so far is that you first use the default renderer, then pass the resulting date string back to a constructor of new `Date` object, which then is further passed to `moment` function. Finally you just return the date with desirated formatting.

Full code:

```
giveitatry: function() {
    return function(text, render) {
        var date = moment(new Date(render(text)));
        return date.format("MMMM Do YY");
    }
}
```

Works similarly well for lists of dates:

```
{{#entities}}
  {{#dates}}
    <div class="span3">{{#giveitatry}}{{.}}{{/giveitatry}}</div>
  {{/dates}}
{{/entities}}
```

You are not alone in this problem. The introduction for helpers / filters that would provide a cleaner solution to this problem is ongoing in mustache.js's issue tracker (see [[1]](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/pull/139), [[2]](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/pull/261)).

Comment: first of all thanks for your help. it's not working yet but i guess i made a mess mixing up things. your code would work with standard mustache right? my guess is i've got some issue configuring expressjs to use mustache with consolidatejs

i've put console.log(text) and console.log(render) inside giveitatry inner function and i get undefined for both

Comment: Yes, my code works in standard mustache (`mustache=0.7.0` with node.js `0.6.15`). See this link for full working code: http://www.coderemarks.com/review/VVNxCngBBWUbmeos

Comment: Oh wait, I think you need to remove the extra dot from your template: Change `{{dates.0.}}` to `{{dates.0}}`. Otherwise you get something like `undefined NaNth NaN`

Comment: still does not work. it might be consolidate and mustache. i'll add my expressjs conf

Comment: console.log(render); console.log(text); gives undefined
undefined (they're both inside giveitatry inner function)

Comment: Have you tried what happens if you instead of Mongoose objects, pass a raw JavaScript object?

Comment: I'm curious: what was the problem?

Comment: bad looping + bad returning of the function inside giveitatry. you helped a lot. thanks